# Does trim need to be enabled inside a VM on a zvol?

Tags: zfs, virtio, trim

zfs and virtio both have trim support, which means, that trim operations can be forwarded by VMs using zvols to the physical underlaying disks. (Please excuse my usage of the word "physical zpool". I use it to distinguish the zpool on the physical disks from the zpool on the zvols). My question with this setup is now:

Since I do have an autotrim service (weekly) running on the physical pool on the host, do I need to also have an autotrim service running on the virtual pool inside the VM which lays on a zvol on the very same physical pool?

Or in other words, will the physical pool know, what has been deleted from the inner zpool on the zvol automatically? Or is the trim operation that is being executed by the VM necessary to tell the physical pool, that the data has been deleted?